# How can I block specific keyboard keys using python's keyboard module?

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events

I've been trying to make a program on Windows 10 that stops people using my screen when I'm away from my screen. I know there is the "Lock" option in the start menu, but my company blocks the use of that for some reason.

I've used tkinter to make a black screen in full screen that can't be taken out of full screen unless you enter a password or insert a physical security key.
But I realise that people, upon seeing this, would just press the windows key and close the window.

So I want to try and make it so that I can temporarily disable specific keys, like ALT, DEL, CTRL and all the function keys so that it can't be closed using the keyboard shortcuts. I also realise that people could just shut down my PC using the physical switch. I do want to keep all of the keys for letters, numbers, symbols and caps lock enabled so that the user can type the password.

I know of ways to do this with keyboard.block_key(), but I do not know what values to put into the parentheses to block only CTRL, ALT, DEL, SHIFT, the Windows key, ESC and all of the function keys. I'm not sure if it is an integer I put in for a key code / ID or if I put in a string.

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no way to do exactly what you are describing, as giving a python program that level of control over the operating system would be very dangerous. Talk to your manager if people touching your work while you are gone is that big of a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that its possible to block specific keys using a python program.

There is a different approach to this, you may be able to run a `time.sleep` function to temporarily disable the keyboard.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes
import wintypes

BlockInput = ctypes.windll.user32.BlockInput
BlockInput.argtypes = [wintypes.BOOL]
BlockInput.restype = wintypes.BOOL

blocked = BlockInput(True)
if blocked:
   try:
   pass # do something
finally:
unblocked = BlockInput(False) # unblock in any
case
else :
   raise RuntimeError('Input is already blocked by another thread!')
```

Above is an example program that I wrote for blocking keys on windows. Instead of the `pass` functions, you could replace that with code for what you want to do. (Example: wait unit your physical security key is entered)

This is a differential approach, and is easier to add to later on:

```
import time
class keyboardDisable():

    def start(self):
        self.on = True

    def stop(self):
        self.on = False

    def __call__(self): 
        while self.on:
            msvcrt.getwch()


    def __init__(self):
        self.on = False
        import msvcrt

disable = keyboardDisable()
disable.start()
time.sleep(10)
disable.stop()
```

If this is really that big of a problem at work, I would recommend setting up a key logger to see if someone really is messing with your computer and report it to your boss.

Comment: Ah, thank you! This should help my situation. I've reported it to my boss and he said that I should just do what I have to do. But thank you as this has helped.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer and upvote if you found it helpful. Best of luck!